# Computer Music Composition

Tags: algorithms, reference-request, genetic-algorithms

I've been looking into computer assisted music composition lately for my school project. While searching for literature I came across [GenJam](http://igm.rit.edu/~jabics/GenJam94/Paper.html), an interactive jazz improvisation software which uses genetic algorithms to produce musical phrases.

I was wondering If anyone has done some work on computer generated music and could suggest term papers, books or other reading material I should look into.

Comment: We have some questions on [music in CS](http://cs.stackexchange.com/search?q=music+is%3Aquestion) you might want to check out.

Comment: its a bit vague could you narrow it down a bit? just a few yrs ago it was rather uncommon but this field has quite a bit of refs now....

Comment: I am more interested in evolutionary music and application of pattern matching, machine learning techniques to compostion

Answer (score 2):

see also eg

- [Wikipedia evolutionary music](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evolutionary_music)
- [A genetic algorithm for producing music](http://www.doiserbia.nb.rs/img/doi/0354-0243/2010/0354-02431001157M.pdf) Matic
- [A fitness function for computer-generated music using genetic algorithms](http://arantxa.ii.uam.es/~alfonsec/docs/artint/music2b.pdf) Alfonseca
- [Computer Models of Musical Creativity](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0262033380) Cope / "asks whether computer programs can effectively model creativity -- and whether computer programs themselves can create"
- [Virtual Music: Computer Synthesis of Musical Style](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0262532611) Cope / "the author and a distinguished group of experts discuss many of the issues surrounding the program, including artificial intelligence, music cognition, and aesthetics."
- [Machine Musicianship](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0262681498) "This book explores the technology of implementing musical processes such as segmentation, pattern processing, and interactive improvisation in computer programs."

Answer (score 1):

Here's some resources that might help you:

The Wikipedia pages on [Algorithmic Composition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algorithmic_composition) and [Computer Generated Music](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_music#Computer-generated_music) give good overviews.

[Wolfram Tones](http://tones.wolfram.com/) is an online music generation tool [based on cellular automata](http://tones.wolfram.com/about/how.html).

[David Cope's work](http://artsites.ucsc.edu/faculty/cope/experiments.htm), including the 1991 book ["Computers and Musical Styles"](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0895792567), [inspired Douglas Hofstadter](http://courses.cs.washington.edu/courses/cse403/03su/materials/Essay-Douglas-Hofstadter.htm).

A [well-cited survey paper](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.3.8064&rep=rep1&type=pdf) by Papadopoulo & Wiggins describes different AI methods for algorithmic composition.

["Algorithmic Composition: Paradigms of Automated Music Generation"](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/321175539X) by Gerhard Nierhaus (2009) is a more modern textbook covering "prominent procedures and classes of algorithms for algorithmic composition."